# list of selected files with file_picker in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

Question from a newbie in Flutter and Dart:
With this code I let a user to pick mulitple mp4/avi files in flutter web:

```
`FilePickerResult? picked = await FilePicker.platform
          .pickFiles(
            allowMultiple: true,
            type: FileType.custom,
            allowedExtensions: ['mp4', 'avi']);`
```

Now I would need an exression to extrcat the file name (not the path) of the selected files. I was hoping in something like this:

`List<File> file_names = picked.files.name.toList();`

But this is wrong.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try map function to extract the name property of each File object in the files list:

```
List<String> file_names = picked.files.map((file) => file.name).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to get `List<File>`

```js
  List<File> files = picked.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
```

Also,`FilePicker` supports picking files from the web so it should not be issue.

And if you're planning to upload files to **firebase** then make sure you upload in `Uint8List` format.